# C# Selenium findElements by XPath returns null

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver

```
IList<IWebElement> firstname = driverOne.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id="+ ((char)34) + "4cd85da6-f2d1-4361-9864-e187dc763f9b" + ((char)34) + "]"));
```

I tried this go get the element from the HTML below, but it returns null, because everytime I reload the page the XPath gets changed, because the element gets created randomly from Angular, I think.

```
<input id="0bad9cfd-028d-404c-a498-17a3f5f1ae81" type="text" data-test="first-name-input" placeholder="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"><!----><!---->
```

I also tried to do it with the Id and the CSS-Selector, but everything is changed after a reload, so I dont know what do...

So how can I get the Element?

Comment: When you say everything is changed, what do you mean by that. Class name changes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using data-test maybe?

```
firstname =driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-test='first-name-input']"));
```

Comment: ty very much Nina

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an ID to html tag strictly like:

`<h1 id="test"> </h1>`

ID will not change after Angular rendering process. You can add Id's to every element you need to access.

Comment: Thats not my HTML and to change it everytime is too much, but ty